# Primes p=4k+1 such that k!+1 is divisible by p

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is it known whether there is a prime $p=4k+1$ such that $k!+1$ is divisible by $p$?

(I conjectured that such primes don't exist, but couldn't prove it.)

Answer (score 38):

There are no such primes $p$.  Write $p=4k+1$ as $a^2+b^2$ with $a$ odd and $b$ even, and by changing the sign of $a$ if necessary suppose that $a\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  Note that $a$ is uniquely defined.  Gauss showed that (see, for example, [Binomial coefficients and Jacobi sums](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1984-281-02/S0002-9947-1984-0722761-X/S0002-9947-1984-0722761-X.pdf) for references, and proofs of this and other similar congruences)
$$ 
\binom{2k}{k} \equiv 2a \pmod p.   
$$ 
Also, by Wilson's theorem we know that $(2k!)^2\equiv (4k)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$.  Using this, and squaring Gauss's congruence, we get 
$$ 
4a^2 (k!)^4 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}. 
$$ 
If now $k! \equiv -1 \pmod p$ then we conclude that $4a^2 + 1\equiv 0 \pmod p$.
Since $4a^2+1$ is $1\pmod 4$ and at most $4p$, we must have $4a^2+1 =p = (2a)^2 +1^2$.  But by the (essential) uniqueness of writing $p$ as a sum of two squares this forces $a=1$ (and so $p=5$).  For $p=5$ we verify directly the claim.

Comment: Where can I find a proof of that congruence?

Comment: @user50519: I added a reference to a paper that discusses this.

Comment: I do not understand the end of your argument: (essential) uniqueness forces $a=1$. Example: $a=-3$ leads to $p=37$, $a=5$ to $101$. What additional information forces $a=1$?

Comment: @RolandBacher: Note throughout that $a^2+b^2=p$.  Note that for example $37=1^2+6^2$, so you can't take $a=-3$ there. (What's being used at the end is that there's essentially only one way to write a prime $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ as a sum of two squares.)

Comment: I see. You need to remember the second sentence ($a$ odd) which I did not. Thanks.