# Does $\binom{2n}{n} \equiv 2 \pmod p$ ever hold?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, congruences

Well, the title does not tell the whole story; the complete question is:

> Are there any primes of the form $p=2n(n-1)+1$, with integer $n\ge 1$, such that
>     $$ \binom{2n}{n} \equiv 2\pmod p ? $$

Primes $p=2n(n-1)+1$ are not that rare: say, of all numbers of this form up to $2\cdot10^{10}$, some 12.7% are prime; however, for none of these primes the congruence above holds true.

A simple heuristic is as follows. Let's say that a prime is *bad* if it satisfies the congruence. If the binomial coefficients $\binom{2n}{n}$ were distributed uniformly modulo $p$, then the probability that a particular prime $p$ is bad would be about $1/p$. Also, the probability that bad primes exist does not exceed the sum of probabilities for all primes $p=2n(n-1)+1>2\cdot10^{10}$ to be "bad". Hence, this probability is at most
  $$ \sum_{n>10^5} \frac1{2n(n-1)+1} < 5\cdot 10^{-6}. $$

Comment: Does this have something to do with the number of points on the curve $y^{n-1}=x^{n-1}+1$?

Comment: @Felipe: having thought for a little while, I don't see any immediate relation. It has to do with $y^{2(n-1)}-x^{2(n-1)}$ being quadratic residues though.

Comment: What do you see for small n when factoring C-2, where C is the middle binomial coefficient?

Comment: @The Masked Avenger: I've just made the computation - nothing to write home about. (I have troubles fitting the results into this comment, but they are absolutely non-illuminating, anyway.)

Comment: Observing that $n(n-1)$ is always even (an interesting fact on its own! cf. http://mathoverflow.net/a/152300/22971), you have a prime of the form $p = 4k+1$. In this light, an earlier answer and link from Lucia (http://mathoverflow.net/a/165441/22971) may be relevant to your question. My hunch is that the information there can be pushed through to answer your question in the negative, but I don't see how to do it. Maybe someone else (or you) will!

Comment: @BenjaminDickman: Thanks for reminding me about mathoverflow.net/a/165441/22971; I will check how relevant it is.

Comment: Not that it matters, but $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n(n-1)+1}=\frac\pi2\tanh\frac\pi2$.

Comment: What is known (if anything) about arbitrary primes $p$?

Comment: @ Włodzimierz Holsztyński: Nothing!

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed up to $n = 1e6$. No example found.

But note that there is probably nothing special about the number $2$. The same holds (also up to $n = 1e6$) with $2$ replaced by $3, 4, 5, 8$.

Comment: Is it Hexadecimal system or $10^6$?

Comment: It is $10^6$, not hexadecimal.